# Paste copied shape in the center of the canvas in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have to paste the copied shape on the center of the visible part of canvas.The canvas is on the panel and panel is having scrollbar and I need to position the shape , so that the center of the shape is the center of the visible canvas.I am also zooming out the canvas and should be able to paste on the center of the zoomed canvas.
Do anybody is having any idea about the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

how you are pasting that i don't know

any way the solution seems to be like this

convert the center point of the panel to Local point of the Canvas.

during pasting.

and this link seems to be useful [Local to Global & Global to Local](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_5.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I have written a draw() function and in the copy function of shape I am calling clone function of event and cloning the shape and then calling the draw().I have to set the x and y positions of the cloned shae exactly at the center of the canvas which is inside the Panel with scrollers.If you could help me in setting the x and y positions of the cloned shape.

Comment: var PanelCenterpoint:point = new point(panel.width /2, panel.height /2);  apply globaltoLocal(PanelCenterpoint); then use this point x and point y for the particular object.

Comment: thanks.But the above code is not working...on zooming or scrolling the visible part changes and i want to paste the cloned shape on the visible part.Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: I think u had not got my point i used this already. apply the globaltolocal() for the canvas. then u might get the varying x y point then u can apply for that. post the code i ll make some correction on that

Comment: var PanelCenterpoint:Point = new Point(container.width /2, container.height /2); 
    var point:Point = page.globalToLocal(PanelCenterpoint); 
    clipBoardItem.x =  point.x;
    clipBoardItem.y =  point.y;

Comment: in the above container is the Panel and page is the canvas.Clipboarditem is the cloned shape

Comment: ok no need of that page.globalToLocal(PanelCenterpoint); use directly var point:Point = globalToLocal(PanelCenterpoint); then u might get